# VB.NET XML get values

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi everyon                                e.

I've got the following XML response from the Musicbrainz webservice: http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5dedf5cf-a598-4408-9556-3bf3f149f3ba?inc=url-rels%20artist-rels&fmt=xml

How would I get the values of the nodes under "member of band" : "begin", "end", "attribute (the instrument the artist plays)", "sort-name" and "artist id"?

I've got so far the following:

```
Dim fullURL As String = "Http://localhost:5000/ws/2/artist/5dedf5cf-a598-4408-9556-3bf3f149f3ba?inc=url-rels%20artist-rels&fmt=xml"

Dim mBrainz = XElement.Load(fullURL)

' pruebas desde aqui

Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load(fullURL)
```

localhost since I've got a local copy of the MB database on a VM machine.

I'm pretty new to XML and this has got me stuck for weeks now. I've searched around but I can find a solution to one node value but it won't go further into getting values like the ID of the artist.

The idea is to get all members of a band - from when to when, instrument played and get their ID so I can search in turn this person to find out what bands he's been a member of.

I would need to assgin each of these values on local variables to process later and to save on a database.

Many thanks for any enlightment.

Juan

Comment: I recommend you look at deserialization.  This lets you convert the xml into a known object model so you can easily refer to things like `metadata.artist.name` to get WhiteSnake.

Comment: I would start by designing your database tables.  Then parsing the xml into the tables.  Then deciding if you want to use xml de-serialize which requires classes to match the xml structure or if you want to create a custom serialize method similar to Mark's LINQPad solution.  I can use Net Library xml linq to do same that Mark did in linqpad.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this solution. I had no idea about serialization/deseralization in VB and looking into it in the documentation it opens up a brand new world for me regarding data manipulation. In VS there is a neet tool, that I didn't know about, that pastes xml and clreates the classes. Been all night working on it and it's wonderful. I already have the DB structure.  I just needed the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the returned XML has a namespace, you first need to import that, then you can use a simple LINQ to XML query to extract the data you want:

```vb
Imports <xmlns:mb = "http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#">

Dim xml = XDocument.Load(fullURL) ' Use XDocument, since it has an XML declaration
Dim result =
    From e In xml.Root...<mb:relation>
    Where e.@type = "member of band"
    Select
        Begin = e.<mb:begin>.Value,
        [End] = e.<mb:end>.Value,
        Instrument = e.<mb:attribute-list>.<mb:attribute>.Value,
        Name = e.<mb:artist>.<mb:sort-name>.Value,
        ArtistID = e.<mb:artist>.@id
```

The result (dumped in LINQPad):

[image: Query Result]

Comment: this is it! Many thanks. Very clean and straighforward. I had no idea about namespaces so I have to read more about it. Many thanks. I don't have enough votes to give you but you have my respect, sir. Thanks